Lightning-Datatable column header tooltip and icons
Is it possible to add in icons to the headers of the LWC Lightning-Datatable? Barring that, is it possible to add a tooltip to the header? I already have many custom column cells, but I haven't been able to figure out how to edit the column headers. (I also hid the default column actions)

You can use the iconName property to identify a SLDS icon to display in the column header. You cannot add a tooltip, as the header already has a built in hover action (to display the rest of the title, when truncated).
